# What does the combo counter improve?

Tags: cthulhu-saves-the-world

Cthulhu Saves the World is advertised to feature a combo-based combat system. Each attack carries a number of hits increasing a combo counter. Certain 'final' abilities reset the combo counter and a few of them are more powerful the higher the combo counter. Many boss fights can be won by using tentacles, lightning, multi-strike, +1 hit passives, etc., to boost this counter very quickly, then using Deathblow to deal thousands of damage in one attack.

Is this all? Does the combo counter also improve normal attacks or other stats?

Answer (score 2):

Each attack type does damage that has a multiplier(number of hits)xdamage.  Your finishing moves multipliers are based off of the combo counter so if your combo counter is at 15 your Deathblow should do 15x(damage) points of damage.

Comment: Yes, but is this all? :)

Comment: As far as I've been able to find or tell. It might also affect the "team up" attacks.